# I am having trouble seeing my website on mobile

Tags: html, css, web

I am making an website and it works perfectly on pc but when I try to preview on phone I got some problems. 
[image]

Can anyone help me?
I got everything inside an div with this properties.

```
width: 960px;
height: 500px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 312px;
clear: both;
position: relative;
top: -250px;
position: static
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try using @media rules in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're giving the elements static heights it won't change when you switch to mobile platforms. Like Adarsh Mohan said, use @media rules. You can define what lay-out you want per size of the screen. For example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 320px){

   .content{height:250px; width:500px;}

}
```

This CSS will only be applied to the div 'content' when the width of the screen is 320px (or lower).

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.